# Avoid having to change the year in dates of formulas

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a spreadsheet that uses the "sumif" function and tallies the months in date ranges;

=SUMIFS(Amount;DPIF;">=1/1/2021";DPIF;"<=31/1/2021")

This formula repeats twelve times (for each month) and with the change from 2021 to 2022 I now have to, manually, change the date (year) ranges in all twelve formulas.

I tried to change just the year (the 2021 in the formula) to reference another cell but Excel does not see it as a date anymore.

How can I make my spreadsheet usable from one year to the next?

Answer (score 1):

**Approach 1**

Rather than hardcoding start/end dates in your `SUMIFS` functions, generate them using Excel formulae and then reference the cells containing these calculated date values. The [`DATE`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/date-function-e36c0c8c-4104-49da-ab83-82328b832349) and [`EOMONTH`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/eomonth-function-7314ffa1-2bc9-4005-9d66-f49db127d628) functions can be used as shown in the screenshot below.

[image: screenshot for generating start/end dates for the 12 months of a specific year]

Your `SUMIFS` formula for January can then be changed to:

`=SUMIFS(Amount;DPIF;">="&Sheet1!B3;DPIF;"<="&Sheet1!C3)`

For the month of January, cell `Sheet1!B3` has the start date of the month and `Sheet1!C3` has the end date. Change these cell references to wherever you put your calculated date values. For February, the start/end date cells are `Sheet1!B4` and `Sheet1!C4`, for March `Sheet1!B5` and `Sheet1!C5`, etc.  If your 12 monthly `SUMIFS` formulae are arranged as a range of 12 rows by 1 column, you will be able to copy the January formula down to the next 11 months.

The ampersands (& signs) in the formulae each concatenate a comparison operator with the value in the referenced cell, so in the changed formula `">="&Sheet1!B3` is effectively equivalent to `">=01/01/2024"` because `Sheet1!B3` delivers the date value of 01/01/2024.

To change the year simply change the value of the year in the appropriate cell - cell `Sheet1!B1` in the screenshot. Your 12 monthly `SUMIFS` formulae will all automatically refer to the new year's start/end dates, eliminating the need for the formulae to be edited.

This approach also manages the end of month date for February in leap years (as shown in the screenshot in cell `C4`).

**Approach 2**

An alternative approach is to convert the `DPIF` date values into month number values by adding an extra range to your existing `Amount/DPIF` ranges using the [`MONTH`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/month-function-579a2881-199b-48b2-ab90-ddba0eba86e8) function as

`=MONTH(date)`

where `date` represents a date cell in the `DPIF` range.

Calling these monthly values `MPIF` means you could then use formulae such as

`=SUMIFS(Amount;MPIF;1)`
`=SUMIFS(Amount;MPIF;2)`
...
`=SUMIFS(Amount;MPIF;12)`

without having to worry about the year at all.

This monthly approach assumes that you do not have multiple years in your data ranges. If you do, it will sum data for all the January's, all the February's, etc which is possibly not what you want.

In this case, a refinement to the solution is to add year values to the data in a `YPIF` range using the [`YEAR`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/year-function-c64f017a-1354-490d-981f-578e8ec8d3b9) function to obtain these values. You would then add a second criterion to the `SUMIFS` formulae to include these year values, for example

`=SUMIFS(Amount;MPIF;1;YPIF;2024)`

Of course this means you would still have 12 formulae to modify each year, even though the edits are slightly simpler than those you currently have. To avoid this put the year value in its own cell and reference it by using a formula such as
`=SUMIFS(Amount;MPIF;1;YPIF;Sheet1!$B$1)`

**Approach 3**

Not one to recommend, but included for completeness, change your formulae to

`=SUMIFS(Amount;DPIF;">=01/01/"&Sheet1!$B$1;DPIF;"<=31/01/"&Sheet1!$B$1)`
`=SUMIFS(Amount;DPIF;">=01/02/"&Sheet1!$B$1;DPIF;"<=28/02/"&Sheet1!$B$1)`
etc

This involves a one-off editing job which will work for years 2021, 2022 and 2023 but will omit 29/02/2024 from February's monthly sum in 2024 unless someone remembers to make a change, and will possibly cause problems in 2025 if not changed back.

Comment: Hi and THANK YOU.

Comment: Oups. Thank you for your solutions. I went with option 1 and I works perfectly. Very clever - I'm impressed.

Comment: Hardcoding parameters into formulae is a particular bugbear of mine. Ultimately, it just makes assuring the quality of worksheets that much more difficult, particularly if the same parameter values are used in multiple places: there is always a risk that one (or more) of the parameters gets overlooked when there is a need to change or update them. All three approaches were based on designing down the numbers of parameters involved: from 24 in your original to 1 in the case of Approach 1.

Comment: @JakobHenriksen if this answer contains the solution to your question, please upvote it and mark it as "correct answer". This will help other users and give a due reward (= reputation) to the person who has taken the time to answer you.

Answer (score 0):

- put the two complete dates (not just the year) each in a separate cell. Then in your formula, replace the date value with references to the cells
- to change all formulas at once, run a "replace all" within your sheet
- next year, change only the date values in the two separate cells